# VB function get data from SQL server

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The vb code is as below:

```
Function GetDCF(vari As String)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim strConn As String
Dim sql As String

strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=xxxxxx;INITIAL CATALOG=xxxxx;INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

cn.Open strConn

sql = "select '" & vari & "'  from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = '" & Range("A2").Value & "' "

rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

GetDCF = rs.Fields(vari)

cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

But it doesn't return a value in excel. Instead, if I replace '" & vari & "' with a real field in sql server, and put GetDCF=rs!fieldname, I did get the value. May I ask where is wrong with GetDCF = rs.Fields(vari)?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be enclosing your field in single quotes in the sql. Suppose the value for `vari` passed into the function is `Person` and your `Range("A2").value` is `Catepillar`, then your sql will look like `select 'person' from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = 'Catepillar'`

Instead:

```
sql = "select " & vari & "  from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = '" & Range("A2").Value & "' "
```

Comment: thanks, it seems "select " & vari & "  from still doesn't work (i guess because vari is a variable in excel) but it's ok now, as I simply use select * from... and everything works fine now. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: vari is of the type `string`, as you declared in the inputs of subroutine at the top. The only reason, I can figure, why it would still be failing is because your field name has a space in it like 'My Field' instead of the more tradition field naming of 'my_field'. If that's the case then you need to enclose the field in square brackets. `sql = "select [" & vari & "]  from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = '" & Range("A2").Value & "' " `

Comment: my field name doesn't have a space. I'm guessing as vari is a variable in excel vba, I can't directly write select vari from... in sql